# Django admin interface doesn't perform server side checks to determine validity of csrf token

Tags: django

I've just had some penetration testers decide that my Django admin is potentially exposed to a CSRF attack. Given that I only heard of a CSRF attack when they told me about this, I'm going with this being a configuration issue on my part only I can't seem to find where.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download Burp Suite Community Edition
2. Open Browser (from within Burp Suite)
3. Sign into your Django admin portal
4. Navigate to "Authentication and Authorization" -> "Users"
5. Select a user
6. Modify the first name attribute (do not click save just yet)
7. Turn "Intercept On" within Burp Suite (this will catch the request before it hits your django app)
8. Back within the browser click "Save"
9. Burp suite will catch the request, at this point you should be able to see something like

```
Cookie: csrftoken=HoBcgZfhlb1W5Km3F7NL37BKv9XkNvGYcYSO6h4LzZxF5ceLbShbcmiSl9py9iY2; sessionid=ioo36waf6i7sclcj33stv8lminx3u36e
Connection: close

csrfmiddlewaretoken=hUR7ZNj0UdeqOBUtoP973QVeQEeHd3KnMu8JP58u81K9O3MbUADxc5CmGEGVzQ2r&username=dev&first_name=tony&last_name=&email=&is_active=on&is_staff=on&is_superuser=on&last_login_0=2020-08-08&last_login_1=09%3A19%3A32&date_joined_0=2020-08-05&date_joined_1=16%3A02%3A29&initial-date_joined_0=2020-08-05&initial-date_joined_1=16%3A02%3A29&_save=Save
```

10. Change the values within the csrftoken and csrfmiddlewaretoken to something else that is 64 char's in length (note, the values for both csrftoken and csrfmiddlewaretoken must match each other, but can be completely different to what they were originally) and for good measure change the value of first_name e.g.

```
Cookie: csrftoken=1234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678; sessionid=ioo36waf6i7sclcj33stv8lminx3u36e
Connection: close

csrfmiddlewaretoken=1234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678&username=dev&first_name=smellysocks&last_name=&email=&is_active=on&is_staff=on&is_superuser=on&last_login_0=2020-08-08&last_login_1=09%3A19%3A32&date_joined_0=2020-08-05&date_joined_1=16%3A02%3A29&initial-date_joined_0=2020-08-05&initial-date_joined_1=16%3A02%3A29&_save=Save
```

11. Forward the request on to the django server
12. You should see a message within Burp Suite saying "The user was changed successfully."
13. You can also validate within the admin portal that the user first name was updated successfully.

The above steps demonstrate that Django is not validating the csrf token value.

Currently, my settings.py contains

```
# sets HttpOnly cookie
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
# sets Secure true
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
# sets session timeout (currently at 15 minutes)
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 15*60

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Django's CSRF protects against cross site request forgery, but not against MITM attacks (which is what you're doing when you say "the values must match").

Comment: @thebjorn, cheers for the comment. I've updated the question, "the value must match each other, but can be completely different to what they were originally". I believe this shows that even with HTTPS enabled the django server is not validating the csrf token value. Is this statement correct?

Comment: How will an attacker read/modify the cookie value?

Comment: Whilst django appears to use random token values, no checks on the server side occur to validate the token.
If an attacker can lure a victim to click on a carefully crafted link (website/email) while having a valid session open, the link can use the cookie details stored in the browser to send a request to the django app without the victim being aware.
Django implements double-submit cookie mechanism to prevent CSRF attacks, however, as long as the value of the CSRF token in the cookie and request body match, the request is successfully processed without verifying the validity of the token.

Comment: Yes, and given that scenario... how can an attacker read/modify the cookie value so it matches the post variable in their "carefully crafted link"?

Comment: @thebjorn good question. The 'modified' csrftoken value doesn't need to match the true value, this is the issue. Django's only requirement is that the csrftoken value match the csrfmiddlewaretoken value. That's it! These 'new' values can be chose at random by the attacker.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is 'by design'.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#csrf-limitations

Answers this specific question in the Frequently Asked Questions section at the bottom of the page...

> ##Frequently Asked Questions##

> Is posting an arbitrary CSRF token pair (cookie and POST data) a vulnerability No, this is by design. Without a man-in-the-middle attack, there is no way for an attacker to send a CSRF token cookie to a victim’s browser, so a successful attack would need to obtain the victim’s browser’s cookie via XSS or similar, in which case an attacker usually doesn’t need CSRF attacks.

> Some security audit tools flag this as a problem but as mentioned before, an attacker cannot steal a user’s browser’s CSRF cookie. “Stealing” or modifying your own token using Firebug, Chrome dev tools, etc. isn’t a vulnerability.

Comment: An answer [should include sufficient context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part(s) of an important link**, to make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. In addition, other users tend to respond negatively to answers which are [barely more than a link to an external site](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), and they [might be deleted](/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

A csrf attack is when an attacker submits their (carefully crafted) form data against your view.

Interesting csrf attacks require that the end-user is logged in (if non-logged-in users can modify data you have bigger problems). To attack a logged in user, the attacker must either (i) run attack-code either when the page is loading (e.g. by hijacking a third-party image file), or (ii) by injecting attack-code into the running page, or (iii) by hijacking the user-interactions with the page (e.g. by presenting your page in an iframe on their site).

Your concern seems to be about situation (i) where a remote site submits carefully crafted form-data to your view from the attacker's site. Something like this will work (at least on a site that doesn't have SameSite set on any cookies), and delete the user:

```
import requests

r = requests.post(
    'https://example.com/admin/auth/user/2/delete/',
    data=dict(
        post='yes',
        csrfmiddlewaretoken='foo',
    ),
    headers={
        'Cookie': "csrftoken=foo;sessionid=<insert-session-id-here>",
        'Referer': "https://example.com/admin/auth/user/2/",
    }
)

print(r.content)
```

Here I've created a random CSRF cookie `"foo"` and sent the same value as a post parameter.

However, to be logged in, I need the sessionid cookie (see `<insert-session-id-here>`), and for that I cannot just insert a random value, nor can I read it from javascript. (If I'm logged in, I can read it from devtools, but that isn't an attack vector).

It's always educational to try to break into your own sites, so I urge you to try :-)
(of course, if you find a security issue, make sure you report it responsibly: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/security/#reporting-security-issues)

Comment: I agree with everything stated here. However, it seems odds that django should issue a CSRF token and not validate it. This is either a BUG or a configuration issue, if it is a configuration issue, what config actually controls this?

Comment: @tmo doing more work doesn't necessarily make things safer. As explained, the attacker would need to have access greater than what this kind of attack affords them to initiate such an attack. Of course, if you feel that strongly about it, you can always write a middleware that signs and verifies csrf tokens - but it's not going to be safer, in any meaningful way, than the existing system.